# [local IP]:[PORT] redirects to public website (Flask, server configuration, local environment)

Tags: flask, server, localhost, local, host

I want to debug a flask app on mobiles.

My application configuration allows to expose the app to the network:

```
application.run(host= '0.0.0.0',port=5000,threaded=True)
```

However, if I load `mylocalIP:5000`, it redirects to `www.example.com`, where the production site is hosted, and cannot figure out where it is written to resolve the redirect.

So I cannot see my local environment but in my local machine, and cannot debug the app on other machines - like mobile phones.

Where should I look to solve the problem ?

I must have changed configuration on my machine somewhere, I don't think it is related to flask.

Note: as alternative , I tried use my local host alias:
I'm using a mac, **System Preferences > Sharing > Internet Sharing** is enabled, other computers in local networks can access my local env at myLocal.local host, but still access to `myLocal.local:5000` is forbidden for other machines but my computer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing, install Fiddler app and configure the reverse proxy on your mobile phone. This [tutorial](https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureForAndroid) will help you to configure fiddler in android applications.

After configuring the reverse proxy, run the flask application on localhost or machine IP and you can access your machine IP on your mobile. Fiddler would also help you to intercept all the calls made to your application. If you don't want to inspect via fiddler you can directly put your mobile on same network of application.